# how to get objects which were created today ? (Django-RestFramework)

Tags: datetime, django-rest-framework

Field of Model :

```
time = models.DateTimeField()
```

How to get objects which were created (only) today (from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59)

like:

```
objects = Model.objects.filter(time__gt=?????????)
```

or ?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

You can use [`datetime.date.today()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.today)  to get the current date and then filter objects based on today's date.

You can do something like:

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today() # date representing today's date
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(time__gt=today) # filter objects created today
```

Here, `qs` represents the objects which were created today.

**Another solution** is to use [`range`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/querysets/#range) which is used to perform lookup between two dates.

Here, `start_date` represents `00:00:00` and `end_date` represents `23:59:59`.

```
import datetime

today = datetime.datetime.today()
start_date = datetime.datetime(year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day, hour=0, minute=0, second=0) # represents 00:00:00
end_date = datetime.datetime(year=today.year, month=today.month, day=today.day, hour=23, minute=59, second=59) # represents 23:59:59
qs = MyModel.objects.filter(time__range=(start_date, end_date)) # today's objects
```

Since you are using Django Rest Framework, you might need to override the `get_queryset()` method in your view and return the queryset containing the objects that were created today.

```
class MyView(..):

    def get_queryset(self):
        ..
        return qs # return the queryset created using the above logic
```

Comment: `qs = MyModel.objects.filter(time__gt=today)` doesn't work for me. I think this will be return objects created (will be created) tomorrow.

Comment: this is working for me :) found ```__date``` more elegant than ```__gt``` tho

Answer (score 2):

```
import datetime

today = datetime.date.today() 

qs = MyModel.objects.filter(time__date=today)
```